# Rangaramanujacharya's commentary on upanishads

Tags: upanishads, resource

Where can I find Sri Rangaramanujacharya's commentaries on the Upanishads?

Comment: @KeshavSrinivasan can help you on this.

Answer (score 2):

At these 2 sites one can find Sri Rangaramanujacharya's commentaries on upanishads:

https://archive.org/details/UpanisadahRangaramanuja/page/n1

https://archive.org/details/IshaToTaittiriyaVishishtadvaitTeekaHNApte1910